# Rails seed association data when two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Has anyone ever come across the situation when you want to seed data into a model that has two columns that both reference the same model?

In models where each column references a unique model, I can seed the relationship data no problem by passing in integers. However, when two columns reference the same model I keep getting the error below.

I can get around this issue by deleting the 2 `belongs_to` relationships in the `match.rb` file (shown below), seeding the data, then re-instating the lines after the seed has completed. But this is an absolute nuisance as I'm resetting the database a good bit during development.

Have I set this up wrong? Thanks for looking.

> **Error message**

```
    rake aborted!
    ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Team(#33344260) expected, got Fixnum(#8019940)
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:216:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:12:in `replace'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:118:in `team1='
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
    /home/alzer/workspace/pawchallenge/db/seeds/09_matches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /home/alzer/workspace/pawchallenge/db/seeds.rb:1:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /home/alzer/workspace/pawchallenge/db/seeds.rb:1:in `each'
    /home/alzer/workspace/pawchallenge/db/seeds.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:543:in `load_seed'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:184:in `load_seed'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:132:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

> **models/match.rb**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team1, class_name: 'Team', :foreign_key => 'team1'
  belongs_to :team2, class_name: 'Team', :foreign_key => 'team2'   
  default_scope { order(:id) } # Always orders the match objects by id when retrieved
end
```

> **models/team.rb**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :match
  default_scope { order(:world_ranking, :rank) } # Always orders the team objects by world ranking then rank when retrieved
end
```

Comment: I think that the problem is not in the associations. Show the code that raises the error.

Comment: I see several syntax liabilities here... For example... If it belongs to `team1` and it has foreign key `team1`, then what will @match.team1 be? An object or an id of an object? You should be clearer... If you can't do anything else, rename the association, not the id

Comment: Second, you don't use plural in `Team` class... You should specify that it `has_many :matches`

Comment: It's only the seed action that throws the error. All the rest of the code works fine when I do the work-around.

Comment: Ruby Racer you've sorted it. I should have said `belongs_to :team` in both cases. I changed it there and it seeds fine now. My excuse is it's late and I'm tired (can you move your post to an answer and I'll mark it as correct). I've always been a bit hazy around naming the associations as singular or plural. Is there a reason why it should be plural?

Comment: Damn it, that's not sorted. Now I'm getting an error in the list of matches `undefined method "name" for 4:Fixnum`. `<%= match.team1.name %>`

Comment: To answer a question you asked, `@match.team1` should return an object of type `Team`

Answer (score 0):

Right I had this wired up all wrong. When setting up the match model I'd used the column names `team1` & `team2` by putting the following in the migration file `t.integer :team1` & `t.integer :team2`

To fix this I rolled it back and changed the migration file to `t.references :team1, index:true` & `t.references :team2, index:true`. This then names the relevant columns `team1_id` & `team2_id`

Then in the model I changed the lines to `belongs_to :team1, class_name: 'Team'` and `belongs_to :team2, class_name: 'Team'`.

The seed file now executes properly and the code all works. Thanks for your help Ruby Racer